# Green color in latex

Tags: color

The default green color is not so dominate in latex, could anyone help me to create the green color like the following figure?[image]

Comment: How about a color picker from some graphics programme and using the RGB values ;-)

Comment: I should stress again the fact, that this image has a wide range of green shades....there is not just one single green shade, so the question itself is 'unclear'...

Comment: Have you looked at the enormous number of predefined colours supported by the `xcolor` package already? There are a very wide range of greens, along with every other conceivable hue, really. (I guess less if you want metallic-looking colours but that's more specialised.)

Comment: @Ginger: If my answer suits your requirements, then consider to accept it please

Comment: hi @Hupfer, how can I accept it? I already click the useful button, what else I can do?

Comment: Click the Checkmark symbol below the vote buttons

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using a color picker tool from a graphics programme it is possible to get the RGB (or whatever values) and define the color accordingly.

I just clicked at a brighter green region to get following definition:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}%

\definecolor{mynicegreen}{RGB}{102,252,102}

\begin{document}
\colorbox{mynicegreen}{\parbox{0.5\textwidth}{\blindtext}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This depends of course on the specific position -- there is huge range of color shades of course.

Comment: what about if i would like to use \green comment for the new color?

Comment: @Ginger: What do you mean by `\green` comment?

Comment: @Ginger TeX is a *macro* language, you are free to define a macro `\green` as shorthand for `\color{mynicegreen}` or `\textcolor{mynicegreen}`.

Comment: The nice green is not so nice anymore in my slides:(

Comment: @Ginger are you using an Acrobat Reader version older than Acrobat Reader X? Versions such as 9 and previous have issues with some colors.

Comment: @ginger If you want `green` to be your definintion of green, just define `\definecolor{green}{RGB}{102,252,102}`